# Cannot access form fields

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to log into this page with my credentials: https://myibd.investors.com/secure/signin.aspx

When I "Inspect" it - i can see the form of class `gigya-login-form`
But when I "View source" this form is not present. I assume that the form is loaded via JS (or something similar). I researched SO but none of the solutions helped. Mainly people advice to wait for a page to load

code with waiting for the element to load for 30s

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

url = 'https://myibd.investors.com/secure/signin.aspx'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'gigya-input-text')))
```

Returns *TimeoutException: Message:* - which means that the element never loads.

Can someone help me to fill in that form and click submit? Thank you!

**UPD.** I also tried going inside of iframe but that did not work as well :( code below

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("signin-iframe"))

username = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
username.send_keys("my_user_name")
```

It throws 
*ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible*
(I tried making it visible following ideas from SO, but no luck)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form is located inside an iframe, so to be able to handle input fields you need to switch to that iframe:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("signin-iframe"))
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@aria-label="Email" and @placeholder="Email *"]')))
username.send_keys("my_user_name")
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@aria-label="Password" and @placeholder="Password *"]')))
password.send_keys("my_password")
username.submit()
```

Comment: Tried doing that as well. Let me find that piece of code.

Comment: Dear Andersson, could you please take a look at my update?  Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you. It now throws: __NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@aria-label="Email" and @placeholder="Email *"]"}__

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! The updated answer seems to work! Do I click the submit button in a similar way?

Comment: You can do `username.submit()` instead

Comment: Hm. I can see the email being filled in, but now I am getting TimeoutException on assigning password variable.